# Use React and BabelJS in a Unity project

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, babeljs, unity-powerui

Hi I'm trying to make BabelJS and React to work from within Unity so I can use new-style JavaScript like Arrow functions () => {}, from within PowerUI. Apparently the Install=Package from within Visual Studio didn't actually allow unity to get the packages, so I manually installed AdvancedStringBuilder, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core, JSPool, Newtonsoft.Json, and React.Core and simply dropped the net45 DLLs in the Unity Assets folder, and there are no compile errors.

However, when I actually want to use BabelJS the way the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) (for C#) shows: 
(at the beginning of the cs file):

```
using React;
```

then later when I want to babel-ify the javascript source code for PowerUI to compile (PowerUI/Source/JavaScript/JavaScriptEngine.cs line ~198):

```
var babel = ReactEnvironment.Current.Babel;
var newSource = babel.Transform(source);
Engine.Execute(newSource); // PowerUI code
```

I get this error (from PowerUI but the same would apply in any case):

```
React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.IReactEnvironment

  at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, React.TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, React.TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x001ce] in <c8732b4de84a482c9ad31b41d7faf4d8>:0 

  at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType) [0x00011] in <c8732b4de84a482c9ad31b41d7faf4d8>:0 

  at React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] () [0x00000] in <c8732b4de84a482c9ad31b41d7faf4d8>:0 

  at React.ReactEnvironment.get_Current () [0x00005] in <c8732b4de84a482c9ad31b41d7faf4d8>:0
```

It seems like React isn't working, does anyone know what else I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: Unity doesn't support JS. It uses UnityScript. A lot of your prior JS experience isn't applicable to it, including Babel.

Comment: @estus it is applicable because I'm using PowerUI which expects ES5 input and I'm trying to convert the input javascript to that from the newer javasciprt syntax

Comment: @estus all I need to know is how to use babelJS to convert new JavaScript to a new JavaScript string, from within unity. I just need the return string

Comment: The thing you're describing is specific to PowerUI and Jint, not to Unity in general, isn't it? https://powerui.kulestar.com/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript

Comment: @estus no I'm simply trying to take a string in ES6 and convert it to a string, simply stirng, a string being a Unity object as well, and the powerUI exectue is a side point. All I'm interested is a string, nothing to do with PowerUI, all PowerUI does is take the new string. All I want is : a string

Comment: @estus Just ignore the PowerUI parts, just how to do I use React and BabelJS in unity?

Comment: What version of Unity do you use? Have you checked what scripting runtime version it uses?

Comment: @frankhermes I'm using unity 2019.1.0b1 personal and I'm pretty sure I'm using .NET 4x

Comment: Hi, I don't know much about Unity or PowerUI, but if you just need a string to be converted to another string -- you could run bablel from command line : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage
on the input you will have ES6 files and on the output you'll have ES5 file. then supply it to whatever you have in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use babelJS or react in Unity.

since Unity 2018.2 the only supported language is C#. Qouted from ["Programming in Unity"](https://unity3d.com/programming-in-unity)

> **What programming languages can you use in Unity?**
>
> Unity supports C#, an industry-standard language with some similarities to Java or C++.

Prior to Unity 2018.2 a language *similair* to JavaScript was supported, called UnityScript. However similair it is **not** Javascript, and not even based on the ECMA standards.

The confusion is understandable though, since even some official Unity resource refer to "UnityScript" as "Js/Javascript", but the two are completely different.

For a more extensive explanation between Javascript and Unityscript see this [wiki.unity3d page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript)

Comment: ReactJS.NET is a C#-made library, I am able to import the DLLs into unity fine, this is nothing to do with javascript, I'm just trying to use the C# library called ReactS.NET to compile a STRING of JavaScript to another String of JavaScript; and JavaScript CAN be used in unit BTW through PowerUI, but that's not what I'm asking, I just want to know how to configure ReactJS.NET in Unity just like it can be configured in many other C# based programs

Comment: if it has nothing to do with reactjs, then you should remove the tag

Comment: @oshellInever said it has nothing to do with reactj,s is has noting todo with JAVASCRIPT, the reactJS.NET library simply comiles a string (which happens to contain javascript) to another string (which would also happen to be javascript) but I'm interested in using the ReactJs.NET extension, nothing to do witj javasript